# How to inject a service to a Job and setup IOC container configuration?

Tags: c#, .net-core, quartz-scheduler, jobs

I set up a `Job` in which I injected a service from `servicecollection`. The problem is that this job (Execute method) could not be run although before injecting any services, it was working properly. 
I think the problem stems from `Dependency Injection Lifetime` because when I change all lifetimes to `Singleton` the job is fired. For the reason that `DbContext` should be `Transient` I have to solve it in another way.
**Statup.cs:**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddDbContext<EFDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Cnn")).UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

            services.AddTransient<CheckTransactionConfirmJob>();
            services.AddTransient<CheckPaymentConfirmationScheduler>();

            services.AddTransient<IPaymentRepository, EfPlanRepository>();
            
        }
```

**PaymentService.cs:**

```cs
        private async Task RunPaymentCheckerJob(Payment payment, Guid userId,
            CheckPaymentConfirmationScheduler scheduler)
        {
            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<CheckTransactionConfirmJob>()
                .WithIdentity(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "CheckConfirmationJob")
                .UsingJobData("paymentId", payment.Id)
                .UsingJobData("userId", userId)
                .Build();

            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "CheckConfirmationGroup")
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                    .WithIntervalInSeconds(20)
                    .WithRepeatCount(12))
                .ForJob(job)
                .Build();
            await scheduler.GetScheduler().ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
        }
```

**CheckTransactionConfirmJob.cs**

```cs
public class CheckTransactionConfirmJob : IJob
    {
        private readonly IPaymentRepository _paymentRepository;
        private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;

        public CheckTransactionConfirmJob(IPaymentRepository paymentRepository, IServiceProvider provider)
        {
            _paymentRepository = paymentRepository;
            _provider = provider;
        }

        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                /// business code
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quartz comes with two built-in alternatives for job factory which can be configured via either calling `UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory` or `UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionScopedJobFactory` (deprecated).
For using Microsoft dependency `UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory` should be called in `ConfigureServices` method:

```cs
    services.AddQuartz(q =>
    {
        q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();
    });
```